# Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm working on a website for my golf association.  I have a few different models but ran into a problem when I tried to incorporate Courses.  Course would represent the course name when a Golf Club has more than one course or the course name is different from the golf club (Example: Troon North Golf Club has two Courses, Pinnacle and Monument).  I'm not sure how to create the association

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rounds, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :clubs, through: :rounds, dependent: :destroy
    // do I need this to be able to do @tournament.rounds.first.course.first.name?
    has_many :courses, through: :rounds

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    belongs_to :club
    // not all rounds will have a course
    has_many :courses, :through => :rounds

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :rounds, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tournaments, :through => :rounds, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :club_images, dependent: :destroy
    // not all clubs will have a course
    has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :club
    belongs_to :rounds
```

I've tried using :through and also without it.  I thought that :through could be used after reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, section 2.4.

```
create_table "clubs", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "address"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "state"
  t.string   "zip"
  t.string   "phone"
  t.string   "website"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "logo_file_name"
  t.string   "logo_content_type"
  t.integer  "logo_file_size"
  t.datetime "logo_updated_at"
end

create_table "courses", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "club_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "rounds", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "tournament_id"
  t.integer  "club_id"
  t.integer  "course_id"
  t.datetime "start_time"
  t.datetime "checkin_time"
  t.datetime "entry_deadline"
  t.decimal  "member_fee"
  t.decimal  "guest_fee"
  t.boolean  "scoring"
  t.boolean  "lunch_included"
  t.text     "comments"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "tournaments", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.date     "start_date"
  t.date     "end_date"
  t.text     "comments"
  t.text     "practice_round_comments"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

When I try to execute @round.courses, I get the following message - ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :rounds in model Round.

I'm a little confused and not sure where I'm off.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The belongs_to association should always be singular. Also, you haven't specified the round_id in the migration for course.

In Tournament model, you can directly access the courses for a tournament by 'tournament.courses'. You don't need to access the has_many relationship by using the 'through'. 
eg

```
@tournament.rounds.first.courses.first.name #is wrong way
@tournament.courses.first.name #is the correct way since you have defined a has_many relationship.
```

The 'through' keyword implements an internal sql join.

In the Round model, you can't access 'courses' because you are accessing it 'through' 'rounds' which hasn't been declared. Please understand how relationships are defined and how they actually work in Rails.

Comment: Thanks on the singular typo.  Maybe my design is flawed but I didn't specify a round_id in Course because the course is really part of the Club setup.  We have a tournament at Troon North on the Pinnacle course once year.  Should I create another Model that links them together like a Round_Course table?